# My parameters are not working in requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation

I am trying to make a listener for LocationUpdates and when I am using both developer/androids tutorial and the tutorial I find on the web the method requestLocationUpdates() is used with googleClientApi, locationRequest and "this" as a third parameter.

This is not working as a parameter for some reason. I have tried different advices from simular questions here on stackoverflow.

I have changed the imoport to

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

I have implemented all methods neccesary

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

   private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient=null;
   LocationRequest mLocationRequest = null;
   private Location mLastLocation;
   private GoogleMap mMap;
```

All works until there is time to use requestLocationUpdates-method at startLocationUpdates in the bottom

```
public void buildGoogleMapApi()
{
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
protected LocationRequest createLocationRequest(LocationRequest mLocationRequest) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    return mLocationRequest;
}
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    createLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
{
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);



        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
    }
    LatLng latLngPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLngPosition).title("YOU ARE HERE!!"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLngPosition));
    mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    startLocationUpdates();
}
```

[image]

I have tried to change this to getApplicationContext() and it did not work.

I have followed a lot of tutorials but nothing have worked so far. Anyone see any mistakes in my code? 
Thanks

Comment: use `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;` instead

Comment: Thanks  tahsinRupam , that was  it!!